# onDownload complete notification - inapp purchase in Android

Tags: android

In my Android application I am downloading a video through an application purchase from [Urban Airship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_Airship).

When I click a particular button in my application the downloading gets started. In such a case, after the download completes fully I want to get a notification or alert so that the button becomes invisible. How can I know that the video has been downloaded completely?

Is there any piece of code I could write to be notified when a download finishes in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private void startDownload() {
        String url = PUT HERE YOUR URL;
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

            // mProgressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            mProgressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon_pitchforkfm);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading file... "
                    + GlobalVariable.Getstrpath().toString());

            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }

        /**
         * This is used for downloading the file in the background
         * process.
         */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub.
            // mp3load();
            int len1 = 0;
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(GlobalVariable.Getstr());
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                              "/download/";
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "PATH: " + PATH);
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();

                // String fileName = "workTest.mp3";
                String fileName = "TEST.mp3";

                File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;

                while ((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    // fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", progress[0]);

            mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            //refreshList();
            Toast.makeText(
                FindFilesByType.this,
                "Downloading of " + fileName + " complete.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Put your code here. That is, button visible/invisible code, etc. This indicates
            //that the file download has completed..

            refreshList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code download .mp3 file from specified path from URL can specify here .Mp4 or other extention as per your requirement.. Happy coding :):)Pragna

Comment: now when you want to start download i.e into the onCreate() then just call this method by the startDownload();

Answer (score 0):

I think you are implementing a thread to download the video. But I suggest implementing the same with [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (also known as [painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)).

If you use `AsyncTask` then you need to take care of thread management. For your case, implement the AsyncTask as below.

Do all the downloading tasks inside the `doInBackground()` method of AsyncTask and implement alert/notification or whatever you want to show inside the `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that.